# When a DropDownList has text not matching the value, similar items will force the selection of the topmost similar item

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList that is filled with data from a database table, in this case, a description.
On the Website it is attached to, the user selects a description and hits a button. The process will then find the matching description in the table and import all of the relevant data for display. This method works perfectly.

However, If instead, I fill the text with the description, and the value with the ItemCode, when I try to have the code use SelectedItem(assuming is used the text field), it will shunt the selection to the topmost of the similar items. for example, a "2x4x12 Pine" and a "2x4x12 Spruce".

The primary key of the table uses ItemCode(2x4x12) and type(pine or spruce). this means that while the description of the two items are different, but the value is the same. could this be why it is shunting the selection to the top of the similar items?

Answer (score 1):

While typing this out I may have rubberduckied the problem.

My best guess is that because multiple items use the same item code, resulting in the same value for multiple fields, that the DDL is selecting the item by value and not text, and this results in the selection being shunted to the top option in a grouping that has the dame value.